# Is there a way to convert a list of integers to a single variable?

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to convert a list of integers to a singe variable.

I tried this (found on another question):

```
r = len(message) -1
res = 0
for n in message:
  res += n * 10 ** r
  r -= 1
```

This does not work for me at all.

I basically need this:

```
message = [17, 71, 34, 83, 81]
```

(This can vary in length as I use a variable to change each one)
To convert into this:

```
new_message = 1771348381
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of `join`, `map` and `str` will do.

```
message = [17, 71, 34, 83, 81]
new_message = int(''.join(map(str, message)))
# 1771348381
```